# Tailwind Grid having 2 form inputs per row

Tags: tailwind-css

A newbie to Tailwind CSS here.

I am trying to create a form using grid where there are 2 form inputs in each row, taking half of the row width.

But for some reasons, the grid is not taking the entire width of the viewport.

[image]

```css
.as-console-wrapper { display: none !important; } /* hide tailwind production warning */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid w-full grid-cols-6 gap-2 bg-white px-4 py-5 sm:p-6">
  <form name="form" method="post">
    <div id="form">
      <div class="col-span-3 border">
        <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_lang">Website Language</label>
        <select id="form_lang" name="form[lang]" class="select select-primary input-bordered mt-1">
          <option value="English">English</option>
          <option value="French">French</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 border">
        <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_siteUrl">Site URL</label>
        <input type="text" id="form_siteUrl" name="form[siteUrl]" required="required" class="input input-bordered input-primary input-bordered mt-1" inputmode="url" value="chum.test" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-span-3 border">
        <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_tagLine">Catchy Tagline</label>

        <input type="text" id="form_tagLine" name="form[tagLine]" required="required" class="input input-bordered input-primary input-bordered mt-1" value="Lets Enjoy" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-span-3 border">
        <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_siteName">Awesome Site Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="form_siteName" name="form[siteName]" required="required" class="input input-bordered input-primary input-bordered mt-1" value="My Network" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-span-3 border">
        <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_rootPath">Installation Root Path</label>

        <input type="text" id="form_rootPath" name="form[rootPath]" required="required" class="input input-bordered input-primary input-bordered mt-1" value="C:\laragon\www\chum\" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-span-6 border">
        <button type="submit" id="form_save" name="form[save]" class="btn btn-primary">Setup Network</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the play link with my full actual code.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/LRPUONstW7

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just need to move the classes applied to the outer div onto the `<div id="form">` element. Then you don't even really need the outer div.

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}


/* hide tailwind production warning */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<form name="form" method="post">
  <div id="form" class="grid w-full grid-cols-6 gap-2 bg-white px-4 py-5 sm:p-6">
    <div class="col-span-3 border">
      <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_lang">Website Language</label>
      <select id="form_lang" name="form[lang]" class="select select-primary input-bordered mt-1">
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="French">French</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-3 border">
      <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_siteUrl">Site URL</label>
      <input type="text" id="form_siteUrl" name="form[siteUrl]" required="required" class="input input-bordered input-primary input-bordered mt-1" inputmode="url" value="chum.test" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-3 border">
      <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_tagLine">Catchy Tagline</label>

      <input type="text" id="form_tagLine" name="form[tagLine]" required="required" class="input input-bordered input-primary input-bordered mt-1" value="Lets Enjoy" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-3 border">
      <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_siteName">Awesome Site Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="form_siteName" name="form[siteName]" required="required" class="input input-bordered input-primary input-bordered mt-1" value="My Network" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-3 border">
      <label class="label-text required text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="form_rootPath">Installation Root Path</label>

      <input type="text" id="form_rootPath" name="form[rootPath]" required="required" class="input input-bordered input-primary input-bordered mt-1" value="C:\laragon\www\chum\" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-6 border">
      <button type="submit" id="form_save" name="form[save]" class="btn btn-primary">Setup Network</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

made changes to your setup

https://play.tailwindcss.com/scZRL0lL6w

if you want 2 column grid with tailwindcss

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-2">
  <div class="border">
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="border">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

you don't have to use col-spans

these two snippets are equivalent

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-6">    <--- 6 columns
  <div class="border col-span-3"> <--- each div takes up 3 columns
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="border col-span-3">
  ...
  </div>
</div>


<div class="grid grid-cols-4">     <--- 4 columns
  <div class="border col-span-2">  <--- each div takes 2 cols
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="border col-span-2">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah. too bad. I am generating the form from PHP backend and not possible to create such separate groupings. I would like to have all the form elements to be under a single grid. Apart from grid, what would be the other options?

Comment: they are under the same grid, if its possible you could make the strcuture like so
<form ...><div class="grid grid-cols-2"><formfield1 /><formfield2/></div></form>